# GHDL cannot find function defined in package

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Using GHDL-4.0.0 I want to compile a VHDL entity which makes a reference to a function that is defined in a separate VHDL package file.
I get a compilation error `error: no declaration for function_name`

Here is a reproducible source:

**common.vhd**

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

package common is
    function Bmax_calc(Bin : natural; R : natural; N : natural; M : natural) return natural;
end package;

package body common is
    function Bmax_calc(Bin : natural; R : natural; N : natural; M : natural) return natural is
        constant a : real := real(R*M);
        constant b : real := log2(a);
        constant c : real := real(real(N) * b);
    begin
        return natural(c) + Bin;
    end function;
end package body;
```

**mydesign.vhd**

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity mydesign is
    generic (
        Bin : natural := 24;
        R : natural := 8;
        N : natural := 3;
        M : natural := 1
    );
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        data_i : in signed(Bin - 1 downto 0);
        data_o : out signed(Bin - 1 downto 0)
    );
end mydesign;

architecture arch of mydesign is
    constant Bmax : integer := Bmax_calc(Bin, R, N, M);
    subtype regsize is signed(Bmax - 1 downto 0);
    signal int_r, int_out : regsize := (others => '0');
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            data_o <= data_i;
        end if;
    end process;
end arch;
```

**build.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
mkdir build
cd build
ghdl -a ../common.vhd
ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys ../mydesign.vhd
ghdl -e mydesign
```

**console output**

```
../mydesign.vhd:22:36:error: no declaration for "bmax_calc"
        constant Bmax : integer := Bmax_calc(Bin, R, N, M);
                                   ^
```

Do I have to specify the package explicitly during compilation?
Does GHDL not support referencing functions in a package?
Or what else might be the issue?

Comment: This is an analysis issue and there is no need to generate the elaboration error because mydesign wasn't successfully analyzed into the current working library. While the library clause for work is implicitly declared the declarations in package common can be made directly visible through a use clause or can be referenced by selected name (an expanded name). Here neither common nor Bmax_calc are directly visible. See for example IEEE .Std 1076-2008 12.3 Visibility, 12.4 Use clauses, 8.3 Selected names, 13.2 Design libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'use' your package before you declare `mydesign` entity to make the package contents visible in the design unit:

```vhdl
use work.common.all
```

or you need to make a direct reference to it:

```vhdl
constant Bmax : integer := work.common.Bmax_calc(Bin, R, N, M);
```